# Customize TFS check in Builds Policy for local machine

Tags: .net, tfs

Is there anyway to customize the "Builds : This policy requires that the last build was successful for each affected continuous integration build definition." policy provided by TFS for some local machines. i want to inherit this policy and want to provide some custom implementation for some local machines. without creating new custom policy.

Comment: Sorry, not totally get your point for this `Builds : This policy requires that the last build was successful for each affected continuous integration build definition.`  How would a build affect other different build definition? It should only show succeed/ failed/ abandoned such as this status with own build definition.